# H2O with R: Memory Requirement

Tags: r, in-memory, h2o

I have been looking into the [H20](http://0xdata.com/h2o/) machine learning platform and was trying to figure out if its use with R allows R to process really large data (>> available RAM on a laptop) or if it is still bound by the amount of RAM? I think since it is "in-memory" that this means that it still requires a very large amount of RAM or server clusters? Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, h20 is an [in-memory architecture](http://0xdata.com/blog/2014/03/h2o-architecture/) and hence limited by physical memory.
They do support about 15 different compression schemes under the hood, including ones designed to compress sparse data.

They say some streaming support is "on the roadmap but not implemented yet".

If your dataset doesn't fit, and you can't compress or encode your datatypes any more efficiently (factor, logical, splitting into ranges, text preprocessing), then you'll need either a big cluster or big cloud instance.

Also, FYI the [support for R](http://0xdata.com/blog/2014/03/h2o-architecture/) is only a subset:

> A note on R: H2O supports an R-like language - not full R semantics -
>   but the obviously data-parallel data-munging aspects of R, and of
>   course all the operators run fully parallel and distributed. There is
>   a REPL. You can use it to add or drop columns or rows, manufacture
>   features, impute missing values, or drop-in many R-expressions and
>   have them run at-scale.

So e.g. use their Pre-Baked Algorithms wherever possible (high-performance native Java implementation) rather than generic R algorithm code.

Is your need prototyping or production?
You might ask if they have any reference customers in production on R-H2O.